# How to update different sub documents based on string in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

The following is the document i'm trying to update :

```
{
    "_id" : "12",
    "cm_AccAmt" : 30,
    "cmPerDaySts" : [ 
        {
            "cm_accAmt" : 30,
            "cm_accTxnCount" : 2,
            "cm_cpnCount" : 2,
            "cm_accDate" : "2018-02-12"
        }, 
        {
            "cm_accAmt" : 15,
            "cm_accTxnCount" : 1,
            "cm_cpnCount" : 1,
            "cm_accDate" : "2018-02-13"
        }
    ],
    "cpnPerDaySts" : {
        "cpnFile" : "path",
        "perDayAcc" : [ 
            {
                "cm_accAmt" : 0,
                "cm_accTxnCount" : 0,
                "cm_cpnCount" : 0,
                "cm_accDate" : "2018-02-12"
            }, 
            {
                "cm_accAmt" : 0,
                "cm_accTxnCount" : 0,
                "cm_cpnCount" : 0,
                "cm_accDate" : "2018-02-13"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to update the two lists **cmPerDaySts** and **cpnPerDaySts** based on the string date field : **cm_accDate**, if a match is available.

The code i've tried until now to achieve this task is :

```
ArrayList<BasicDBObject> filter = new ArrayList<>();
filter.add(new BasicDBObject("_id", "12").append("cmPerDaySts.cm_accDate", "2018-02-12"));
filter.add(new BasicDBObject("_id", "12").append("cpnPerDaySts.perDayAcc.cm_accDate", "2018-02-12"));

Document document2 = mongoCollection.findOneAndUpdate(new BasicDBObject("$or", filter),
        new BasicDBObject("$inc",
                new BasicDBObject("cmPerDaySts.$.cm_accAmt", 15).append("cm_AccAmt", 15).append("cmPerDaySts.$.cm_accTxnCount", 1)
                        .append("cmPerDaySts.$.cm_cpnCount", 1).append("cpnPerDaySts.perDayAcc.cm_accTxnCount", 1)),
        new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().upsert(false).returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER));
System.out.println(document2.toJson());
```

But it ends up failing with the below exception :

**Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16837: 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update:**

i want to achieve this in a single update query not multiple. can anyone point me in the right direction or approach to solve this.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to if else kind of update which is not possible. Also,  behavior of positional operator for two arrays is not defined. positional operator by design built a to work with single array. You can atomically update both lists in two separate updates.

Comment: @Veeram actually i'm having multiple instances of my application running because of this i'm looking for a single update query solution which gives me the guarantee that the document that is returned hasn't been touched by my other instances... trying to take advantage of the fact that mongo db is thread safe at the document level.